# Как сделать выравнивание ответа по левой стороне?

Tags: python, строки, символы

моя программа работает верно, но я не знаю как вывести правильно, прошу помочь.
Программа запрашивает у пользователя строку, а затем отображает список символов в ней (включая пробел). Для каждого элемента списка программа должна выводить символ, количество раз, которое этот символ встречается в строке, и частоту встречаемости этого символа в строке (в виде процентов от общей длины строки). При этом при рассчётах регистр символов (заглавный или прописной) не должен учитываться. Список должен быть отсортирован по частоте встречаемости по убыванию
Код:

```
s = input("Введите строку: ") 
dic = {}
for i in s.lower():
    dic[i] = dic.setdefault(i, 0) + 1
print("Символ   Количество   Частота ")
print("------   ----------   ------- ")
print('\n'.join([f'{it[0]:8} {it[1]}  {s.lower().count(it[0]) / len(s) * 100:14}'               
for it in sorted(dic.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)]))
```

Как должно выводить:
Введите строку: Леша на полке клопа нашел

```
Символ Количество Частота
------ ---------- -------
л      4          16.0
а      4          16.0
       4          16.0
е      3          12.0
ш      2          8.0
п      2          8.0
о      2          8.0
н      2          8.0
к      2          8.0
```

Как выводит у меня:

```
Символ Количество Частота
------ ---------- -------
л      4          16.0
а      4          16.0
       4          16.0
е      3          12.0
ш      2           8.0
п      2           8.0
о      2           8.0
н      2           8.0
к      2           8.0
```

То есть, подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать выравнивание по левой стороне для ответов по частоте?

Comment: `{it[0]:8}` - почему Вы тут делали выравнивание, а в других местах нет? Отсюда и полученный результат.

Comment: `print('\n'.join([f'{it[0]:>4} {it[1]:10}  {s.lower().count(it[0]) / len(s) * 100:11}'
                 for it in sorted(dic.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)]))`

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/prettytable/

Comment: @МихаилМуругов я исправил, сделал выравнивание для колонки частота, но не совсем понимаю, как сделать выравнивание для колонки частота по левому краю